# Show images from IQueryable in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, view, iqueryable

I have a question about showing images loaded from a mysql database in a view.

In my database table "deliverables" I have "item_id", "deliverable_image" and "afstudeerrichting_id". "item_id" and "afstudeerrichting_id" are FK from other tables.

I want to show the images when afstudeerrichting_id = ..

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = repository.GetIdsOfImages(1);
    return View(model.ToList());
}
public ActionResult ShowImage(int afstudeerrichtingid)
{
    IQueryable<byte[]> data = repository.GetImages(afstudeerrichtingid);
    var thedata = data.First();
    return File(thedata, "image/png");
}
```

**Repository** (where I get the images):

```
public IQueryable<long> GetIdsOfImages(int afstudeerrichtingid)
{
    return from deliverable in entities.deliverables
    where deliverable.afstudeerichting_id.Equals(afstudeerrichtingid)
    select deliverable.item_id;
}
public IQueryable<byte[]> GetImages(int afstudeerrichtingid)
{
    return from deliverable in entities.deliverables
    where deliverable.afstudeerichting_id.Equals(afstudeerrichtingid)
    select deliverable.deliverable_image;
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach(var imgID in Model.DeliverablesIDsList)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage", "Deliverable", new { DeliverableID = imgID })" />
}
```

In my **Viewmodel:**

```
public List<long> DeliverablesIDsList { get; set; }
public int DeliverableID { get; set; }
```

Now I get the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'GDMfrontEnd.Models.DeliverableViewModel'.

What should I change in my ViewModel? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no need to add tags to titles, that's what tags are for! Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:
1) pass to the view a list of images' ids, and build  list like this

```
@foreach(var imgId in model.ImgIdsList)
{
<img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage", "Deliverable", new { imageId = imgId })" />
}
```

2) in controller, which open this view, simply build a ImgIdsList (probably you need a GetIdsOfImagesWithAfstudeerichtingid(int afstudeerrichtingid), which would return a list of int)
3) you should your ShowImage method - not pass afstudeerrichtingid, but unique id of image; of course in this method you should method like GetImageById(int id).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I still got an error. Do you know what I am doing wrong? (Updated my post)